# Array.find (and other similar methods) does not implicitly return `undefined`

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

`Array.prototype.find` must return `T | undefined`.

But for some reason in my (automatically generated NestJS) environment TypeScript implicitly has only `T` as the return type of such methods.

How should I make TypeScript automatically inferr that `find` must return `T | undefined`?

Comment: Remember to [never show images of text](/help/how-to-ask). Put the actual code and its output in your post, using normal code formatting. And because the browser doesn't run TS, but JS: what does the _browser_ report as being in the array when you try to `.find` an element? (console log the array.slice(), and explain why, given your find criteria, that should yield an `undefined`)

Comment: Sorry for the screenshot! I attached it to show what's displayed while hovering over my code.
I know the `const task` can be undefined, but I want to use Typescript in as strict as possible way.

Comment: Do you have the [`strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) enabled?

Comment: It helped, thank you! `tsconfig.json` had this rule enabled. Disabling it resulted in exactly what I wanted

Comment: @WashingtonIrving Can you clarify? If you disable that option, then typescript will *not* include `undefined` in the return type of `.find`, which sounds like the opposite of your desired behavior. If it is working how you want, all is well, but disabling that option _shouldn't produce the result you describe_, so I just want to confirm.

Comment: @CRice, well, It's just my english again, I set the rule to `true` and this brought the desired behaviour

Comment: I didn't see the comment - happy to delete my answer for @CRice to get post his and you mark as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at strictNullChecks compiler option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

> When strictNullChecks is false, null and undefined are effectively
> ignored by the language. This can lead to unexpected errors at
> runtime.
>
> When strictNullChecks is true, null and undefined have their own
> distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them
> where a concrete value is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
const task: Task | undefined = this.tasks.find((task) => task.id === id);
```

Comment: This indeed will result in what I want, but I think it would be better to leave this on Typescript and not explicitly specify the undefined type when creating a new variable.
In other words, I think the best possible option would be somehow telling TS that `find` must return either `T` either `undefined`

Comment: Not sure I am following. You want to tell TS that this will return an object of type "Task" or undefined? Like: const task = this.tasks.find((task) => task.id === id) as Task | undefined;

Comment: Sorry for my english.
I want Typescript to automatically inferr `Array.prototype.find()` method's return type as `T | undefined`.
For some reason in my environment Typescript inferrs find's return type only as `T`.